# Multiple TagEntry in a page for Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using `TagEntry` created by [Daniel Luberda](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls). This component is working fine but if I want two `TagEntry` on my page, only the second one appears on the page (as you can see in the image below).

[image]

I tried to change it but I can't understand why it doesn't work.

Has someone my same problem? How did you fix it? Is there another similar component?

### Update

I add two `TagEntry` in a `Grid` with two rows. The code is:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <local:TagEntryView x:Name="tagEntryEnd" TagItems="{Binding WordEndItems}" 
                        Placeholder="{localize:Translate WordItemTranslateWord}" 
                        PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource palegreyColor}"
                        TagTappedCommand="{Binding RemoveTagEndCommand}" TagSeparators=";">
        <local:TagEntryView.TagItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame BackgroundColor="{StaticResource baseColor}"
                       OutlineColor="Transparent" 
                       Padding="10,5" HasShadow="false" CornerRadius="5">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="White" />
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:TagEntryView.TagItemTemplate>
    </local:TagEntryView>
    <local:TagEntryView x:Name="tagEntryStart" TagItems="{Binding WordStartItems}" 
                        Placeholder="{localize:Translate WordItemOriginalWord}" 
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource palegreyColor}"
                        TagTappedCommand="{Binding RemoveTagCommand}" TagSeparators=";">
        <local:TagEntryView.TagItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame BackgroundColor="{StaticResource baseColor}" 
                       OutlineColor="Transparent" 
                       Padding="10,5" HasShadow="false" CornerRadius="5">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="White" />
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:TagEntryView.TagItemTemplate>
    </local:TagEntryView>
</Grid>
```

The result is the same. Also, if I try to add a new word, I receive an error because the app can't update the list of word.

Comment: Are both `EntryTag` in the same `Grid`? If so, make sure to have at least 2 `RowDefinition` and set each `EntryTag` to a different row.

Comment: @RogerLeblanc I tried to create two `Grid` but the result is the same.

Comment: 2 `RowDefinition` inside the same `Grid`. Can you update your post with your XAML code, it will be easier to spot an error than just trying to guess.